# Azure SQL Database Access From Windows Desktop Client App

Tags: .net, azure, desktop-application

I wanted to access a database hosted in Azure but dont want to expose the database credentials to users. The access to database will be from an desktop app, which may be installed by any one.

**Client:** .NET Windows App (Desktop)
**Database:** hosted in Azure

What is the best way to accomplish this without compromising the security of database? Please suggest some thing. samples or quick starts from Microsoft.

Comment: Skip the database and put a webservice front end between the app and the database. Then the webservice has the credentials to the database and no client. Otherwise you will need to encrypt the connection string.

Comment: Which Azure service you are referring here? Please also specify any sample or quick start.

Comment: Create your own webservice `api` in Azure which will be a front end to the database. Check out this link to get you started [Create And Deploy Your First .NET Core App In Azure App Service](https://medium.com/@lifei.8886196/how-to-deploy-net-core-web-api-to-azure-a127bfb20d09)

Comment: I think I understand where you are coming from a bit better, I would advise to learn about APIs but to get your app going, just encrypt the db string and decrypt it.

Comment: This means I have to include the encryption keys in my app, which I dont want to.

Comment: Does the below response answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Here are 2 ways in which you can achieve this:

**EF Core in WPF (.NET Framework):** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/wpf#use-the-object-option-for-creating-wpf-data-sources

**EF Framework in WPF (.NET Core):** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/wpf

Comment: This not what I am looking for. I need to access a database which is hosted in Azure. The client used to access is a Windows Desktop App. This client application will complete couple of transactions as required.  I dont want to create a user for each installation of my Windows Desktop App.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirements. Let me know if it answers your question.